# How do I remove .html extensions from my urls?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

How do I remove .html extensions from my urls?
 I'm really new to this and have read many articles on this issue, but all the conflicting information has confused me and nothing has seemed to work!

My htaccess:

---

```
# Begin password protection #
#AuthName "Password Protected"
#Require valid-user
#AuthUserFile "/home/users/web/b244/ipg.akaambcouk/.htpasswd"
#AuthType basic
# End password protection #

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php


ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php




# BEGIN WordPress
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase //
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#</IfModule>
# END WordPress
#Weebly Additions Start
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php

# Send send no-cache headers for root (/) and (.html) files
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(^/|\.html)$" HTML_FILE
Header add Pragma "no-cache" env=HTML_FILE
Header add Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate" env=HTML_FILE
Header add Expires "-1" env=HTML_FILE


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*WeeblySiteLogin=Holland47\!.*$
RewriteRule ^(episodes\.html|send\-music\.html|facebook\.html|feeling\.html|bitch\.html|tracks\.html|bits\-and\-pieces\.html|beachball\.html|portland\-place\.html|white\-food\-for\-free\.html|podcast\.html|late\-at\-night\.html|index\.html||safe\-distance\.html|art\.html|contact\.html|you\-got\-to\-love\-me\.html|pretty\-mess\.html|up\-and\-over\.html|release2gether\.html|velvet\.html|disco\-twat\.html|email\.html|here\-comes\-the\-sun\.html|subscribe\.html|inside\-out\.html|micallef\.html|tuningfunktionen\.html|what\-have\-you\-done\-to\-me\-lately\.html|devils\-work\.html|a\-vauxhall\-noite\.html|handbag\.html|lolas\-descent\.html|close\-my\-eyes\.html|earth\-stops\-turning\.html|caught\-out\-there\.html|bring\-the\-wilder\-side\.html|revamp\.html)$ /login.php


RewriteEngine On


# stop condition
RewriteRule ^mobile/.*$ - [L]


# only process HTML files
# ----------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule (^|\.html)$ - [S=1]
        # is an html file, start the tests...

RewriteRule .* - [S=9]
        # NOT html file, skip past mobile rules...


# tests
# ----------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mobile$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?m [CO=is_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},CO=disable_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]
        # set cookies, redirect...

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^full$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [CO=disable_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},L,R]
        # set cookies, redirect...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*is_mobile=0
RewriteRule .* - [S=6]
        # skip past mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*disable_mobile=1
RewriteRule .* - [S=5]
        # skip past mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)\s*is_mobile=1
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
        # go to mobile rules...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [CO=is_mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST},S=1]
        # go to mobile rules...

RewriteRule .* - [CO=is_mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S=2]
        # set cookie, skip past mobile rules...


# mobile rules
# ----------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^$ /mobile/index.html [S=1,PT]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [PT]
#Weebly Additions End
```

Comment: Why are you posting your whole .htaccess file? That doesn't mean you have actually tried something, does it? Show us what you have tried and the things that don't work instead.